# Change the value of textfield to another language when get textfield.text in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

when I get `mytextfield.text` the result is this: "۱۲۳۴" which is a Persian number of "1234".
I have a method which converts Persian text to English text.
 
I want to get the English text when getting text using `mytextfield.text`

solution 1:
I can realize when the user changes the textfield then I can change it to what I want. but its performance is not good because user might want to change it several time I just want to convert it when I want to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a sub-class of UITextField and overriding `.text`?

In your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TranslatingTextField : UITextField

@end
```

In your .m file

```
@implementation TranslatingTextField

- (NSString *)text {
    return MyTranslation(super.text); // Your translation is called here
}

@end
```

If you are using **Interface Builder** make sure to specify `TranslatingTextField` as the class for the text fields you want to use this class for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding a UIButton with a IBAction, and only when the button is tapped, you get the text ?

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_sender : AnyObject){ // Here you get the text and convert it}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I want to get the converted one every where. just with typing "myTextField.text"

Comment: Well there's not much you can do without knowing when the user is done typing (if you want it to have good performance as you said).

Answer (score 0):

I probably do not understand your question, but I will try an answer anyway.
I assume your `UITextField` is setup in storyboard, and you defined an outlet from your code to it, something like

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *mytextfield;
```

So you can access the textField by program by its identifier.
Or if you did setup the `mytextfield` by program anyway, you can also access it in the same way.

I assume, you know the times when you want to read `mytextfield.text` to convert the text to English, and I assume you have a method to convert the text to English, something like

```
-(NSString)convertToEnglish:(NSString *)text {…}
```

Why don’t you simply read the textField text and feed it into this method, like

```
NSString *englishText = [self convertToEnglish: mytextfield.text];
```

But as I said, I probably did not understand your question…

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I don't want to call a method every time I need to access the text.

Comment: You can add that method into  `Util` and you can reuse at any place of code . without any method how you will covert , or else you can create extension of `UITextFiled` and you and get custom custom text, try using extension  @FattanehTalebi

Comment: @FattanehTalebi , Check my answer  and try the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as you want using category in `Objective-c`, see the implementation below .

**UITextField+Category.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

    @interface UITextField (Category)

    @end

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**UITextField+Category.m**

```
#import "UITextField+Category.h"

@implementation UITextField (Category)

- (NSString *)text {
    return ConvertToEnglish(super.text); //Call your Util function From here
}


@end
```

**Uses**

```
     #import "UITextField+Category.h"

- (void)whenYouWant {
    //Just call txtName.text Call anywhere in the class :  
    NSLog(@"%@", self.txtName.text);
}
```